# Interactive Session in Tensorflow - different output for convolution operator

Tags: tensorflow, python-3.5

I am new to tensorflow and I am having an issue with InteractiveSession.

In the following code:

```
import tensorflow as tf

def weight_variable(shape):
  initial = tf.random_uniform(shape, 0, 10, seed=1, dtype="int32")
  print("weights=\n",initial.eval())
  return tf.Variable(tf.to_float(initial))

def conv2d(x, W):
  return tf.nn.conv2d(x, W, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')


# first dimension: Number of examples to train on, 2nd and 3rd: example width and height, 
# last one is: the number of channels 

x = tf.to_float(tf.Variable([[[[1],     [4],    [5],    [6],    [7]],  
                             [[10],   [11],   [22],    [9],    [8]],  
                             [[24],   [25],   [20],   [21],   [19]],  
                             [[14],   [12],   [13],    [3],   [18]],  
                             [[15],   [16],   [19],   [18],   [17]]]])) # 1 example of 5x5 one channel image


sess = tf.InteractiveSession()

# The first two dimensions are the patch size, the next is the number of input channels, 
# and the last is the number of output channels. 
W_conv1 = weight_variable([2, 2, 1, 1]) #[3,3,3,64]

conv = conv2d(x, W_conv1)


sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())

print(sess.run(conv))

sess.close()
```

when I comment the line:

```
print("weights=\n",initial.eval())
```

I get different results when I print the convolution `print(sess.run(conv))`. I understand that keyword eval interacts with the session, but the way I understand is that it shall not change the output if I use it or not.

Here is the output I get when using `initial.eval()`:

> [[[[7]]
>
> [[9]]]
>
> [[[3]]
>
> [[2]]]] [[[[ 156.]    [ 209.]    [ 278.]    [ 167.]    [  79.]]
>
> [[ 389.]    [ 472.]    [ 337.]    [ 319.]    [ 179.]]
>
> [[ 386.]    [ 332.]    [ 314.]    [ 254.]    [ 181.]]
>
> [[ 293.]    [ 317.]    [ 262.]    [ 360.]    [ 171.]]
>
> [[ 143.]    [ 168.]    [ 163.]    [ 154.]    [  17.]]]]

and when I comment that line, I get:

> [[[[  95.]    [ 150.]    [ 173.]    [ 148.]    [  73.]]
>
> [[ 291.]    [ 390.]    [ 337.]    [ 236.]    [ 113.]]
>
> [[ 459.]    [ 417.]    [ 374.]    [ 363.]    [ 187.]]
>
> [[ 283.]    [ 287.]    [ 211.]    [ 271.]    [ 177.]]
>
> [[ 249.]    [ 283.]    [ 295.]    [ 279.]    [ 119.]]]]

Note that the 156 changed to 95 and the rest of the output of the convolution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because of how seeds work for RNG. Setting an op-level seed in `tf.random_uniform` provides a fixed starting point for pseudo-RNG, but *does not* mean that repeated evaluations of the op will produce the same random numbers. This can be seen in the docs if you check out [tf.set_random_seed](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/api_docs/python/constant_op.html#set_random_seed) and via a toy example that calls `eval()` twice and prints the output:

```
In [2]: initial = tf.random_uniform((5,), 0, 10, seed=1, dtype="int32")
   ...: print("weights=\n",initial.eval())
   ...: print("weights=\n",initial.eval())
   ...: 
('weights=\n', array([7, 9, 3, 2, 7], dtype=int32))
('weights=\n', array([3, 5, 5, 4, 9], dtype=int32))

In [3]: initial = tf.random_uniform((5,), 0, 10, seed=1, dtype="int32")
   ...: print("weights=\n",initial.eval())
   ...: print("weights=\n",initial.eval())
   ...: 
('weights=\n', array([7, 9, 3, 2, 7], dtype=int32))
('weights=\n', array([3, 5, 5, 4, 9], dtype=int32))
```